# Two dots in dart (..)

Tags: dart, flame

I was reading the example game code in the Flame game engine.

Code:

```
MyGame() {
  add(Square()
    ..x = 100
    ..y = 100);
}
```

this was the code in the repository (line 59-63): https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

I have seen this notation earlier but I never understood what (`..x` and `..y`) means.

What does `..` represent here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a cascade notation in Dart, instead of just setting the value like `.` would, it also returns the object you are working on.

So since `add` here wants a `Component`, `Square` (which is a component) is first created and then x is set to 100 and returns the same square and then y is set to 100 and returns the same square again which is then sent in to `add`.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-